# Why does it literally return 0 at the end of the output

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>



using namespace std;

/*
Function Name: weightConv
Purpose: To take the weight and convert the following number to the coressponding weight unit
Return : 0
*/
  double weightConv(double w, string weightUnit)
{

      if (weightUnit == "g" || weightUnit == "G" )
        cout << " Mass = " <<  w * 0.035274 << "oz";
    else if (weightUnit == "oz"||weightUnit == "OZ"||weightUnit == "oZ" ||weightUnit == "Oz")
        cout << " Mass = " <<  w * 28.3495 << "g";
    else if (weightUnit == "kg"||weightUnit == "KG"||weightUnit == "Kg" ||weightUnit == "kG")
        cout << " Mass = " <<  w * 2.20462 << "lb";
    else if (weightUnit == "lb" ||weightUnit == "LB" ||weightUnit== "Lb" ||weightUnit == "lB")
        cout << " Mass = " <<  w * 0.453592 << "kg";
    else if (weightUnit == "Long-tn" ||weightUnit == "LONG-TN"|| weightUnit == "long-tn" || weightUnit == "long-ton")
        cout << " Mass = " <<  w * 1.12 << "sh tn";
    else if (weightUnit == "sh-tn" || weightUnit == "SH-TN")
        cout << " Mass = " << w / 0.892857 << " Long tons";
    // one other converstion that was not listed in the project desription (stones<->tons)
    else if (weightUnit == "s" || weightUnit == "S")
        cout << " Mass = " << w * 0.007 << "tons";
    else if (weightUnit == "tons" || weightUnit == "Tons" || weightUnit == "TOns" || weightUnit == "TONs"|| weightUnit == "TONS")
        cout << " Mass = " << w * 142.857 << "stones";
    else
        cout << "Is an unknown unit and cannot be converted";

    return 0;
}// end of weightCov function


int main()
{
    for (;;)
    {
        // variable declaration
        string user;
        double mass;
        string unitType;

        //Prompt user to enter values
        cout << "Enter a mass and its unit type indicator(g,kg,lb,oz,long-tn,or sh-tn)" << endl;
        cin >> mass >> unitType;


        // Output Results
        cout << weightConv(mass, unitType) << endl;
        cout << "Would you like to do another calculation?(yes/no)";
        cin >> user;

        //Loop asking user if they want to do another calculation 
        if (user == "yes")
        {
            cout << "Enter a mass and its unit type indicator(g,kg,lb,oz,long tn,or sh tn)" << endl;
            cin >> mass >> unitType;
            cout << weightConv(mass, unitType) << endl;
        }
        else if (user == "no")
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }// end of for loop
}// end of main
```

Program works well except for one error. When the results print out it literally adds a zero at the end. I know I am returning 0 at the end of the function but if return weightConv() it's infinite recursion. Can anyone help me so that it just returns the answer and not zero at the end. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because you send `weightConv` to output. Just call it as a void function.

Comment: Thanks, yea I just realized that I could make it void. I was trying to call it like this cout << " Mass = " << weightConv(mass, unitType) << endl; but void just takes the funciton call like weightConv(mass,unitType); Thanks for the reminder lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just printing the converted value but you're not returning it. Each of those if blocks should contain a return statement returning the result of the computation.